# What are the security implications when dealing with cloud on boarding services like Migrationwiz or Skykick?

Tags: cloud-computing

There is a large push these days to move Email and communication to the cloud. Such as Google Apps, Office 365 or Hosted Exchange.

Many company's hire partners to assist with these moves. Most partners use Migrationwiz or Skykick to on-board there customers.

What are the security implications of using a 3rd party service like Skykick or Migrationwiz to migrate data. At some point the data obviously goes though there infrastructure.